# Openshift Express app with ES6

Tags: express, reactjs, openshift, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to make ReactJS app with server side rendering and put it into Openshift server.
I want to use ES6 features with Babel and I can say "I'ts weird, it works on my PC". But on Openshift not.

Yes. I have necessary things and it's ok without ES6

```
app.set('port', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 3000);
app.set('ip', process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1');
```

No. babel/register does not helping

```
require('babel/register')({});
```

No. These solutions also not

```
"start": "node --harmony bootstrap.js"
"start": "babel-node bootstrap.js"
```

Yes. I have main

```
"main": "bootstrap.js"
```

My error is 'failed to start (port 8080 not available)', but it's about because app can't start and it's not responding.

I want my ES6 back :( Can you help?

Comment: Post the logs here. Run `rhc tail`